# Android работа с SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Создан класс для работы с бд наследующий SQLiteOpenHelper. Есть одна активити в которой инициализируется объект класса, и два фрагмента которые тоже должны работать с базой данных(добавление и получение данных). Если с созданием все понятно, то как работать с бд во фрагментах не совсем понятно. Если можно подробнее объяснить все это.

Comment: создаете в фрагментах по экземпляру класса взаимодействия с БД и работаете. В чем именно у вас проблема из вопроса не понятно

Answer (score 0):

Не понятен вопрос.

Допустим, у вас работает база, но вы не можете передать ее во фрагмент. Не могу придумать причин почему вам не удается передать базу во фрагмент обычным сеттером. Или можете сделать объект для взаимодействия с базой синглтоном или статическим, тогда он доступен откуда угодно. Для подобных классов это нормальная практика

Если база не работает, то зачем упоминать фрагменты?